# How to run a piece of code if the select fields gets changed(js/jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, select

I have build a select field styling plugin with jquery, and this works fine, but some users are using js/jquery to add new options to the select field, so I need a way that the plugin will auto update it self. I dont want to re-call the plugin so is there a way to do this?

Comment: Can you show us some example code in JSFiddle? Just add a `select` with dummy values, add your styling and code that invalidates your styling. We'll be able to give you best solution...

Comment: Without code it's hard to tell for definite, but the best method is usually to create a `refresh` method in the plugin which adds the styling again. This can be called after the amendments have been made. Something like `$("#mySelect").plugin('refresh');`

Comment: You need to accept some answers to your questions. Otherwise there is no impetiteos to answer them.

Answer (score 1):

```
 $(selector).change(function(){
     // do something when select is changed
     alert( $(this).val() );
  });
```